# Merge objects based on id and its properties in an arrays

Tags: javascript, node.js, underscore.js

I am trying to merge two multi level objects with in an array using same id. Please help.

The input array of objects looks like this

```
{
    "data": [
       {
            "id": 1,
            "movieId": 1,
            "user": "test@test.com",
            "title": "test Project",
            "desc": "test 123 test 123test 123test 123test 123",
            "status": "Yes",
            "movies":[{
                "id": 1,
                "title": "Movie 1",
                "desc": "Movie 1 Movie 1 Movie 1 Movie 1",
                "status": "Yes",
                "images":[{
                        "id": 1,
                        "fileType": "image",
                        "fileName": "movie1.0.jpg",
                        "filePath": "images\\movie1.0.jpg",
                        "fileExten": ".jpg"
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 2,
                        "fileType": "image",
                        "fileName": "movie1.1.jpg",
                        "filePath": "images\\movie1.1.jpg",
                        "fileExten": ".jpg"
                }],
                "videos":[{
                        "id": 4,
                        "fileType": "video",
                        "fileName": "movie1.0.mp4",
                        "filePath": "videos\\movie1.0.mp4",
                        "fileExten": ".mp4"
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 5,
                        "fileType": "video",
                        "fileName": "movie1.1.mp4",
                        "filePath": "videos\\movie1.1.mp4",
                        "fileExten": ".mp4"
                }]
            }]
        },
        {
            "id": 1,
            "movieId": 3,
            "user": "test@test.com",
            "title": "test Project",
            "desc": "test 123 test 123test 123test 123test 123",
            "status": "Yes",
            "movies":[{
                "id": 3,
                "title": "Movie 3",
                "desc": "Movie 3 Movie 3 Movie 3 Movie 3",
                "status": "Yes",
                "images":[{
                    "id": 8,
                    "fileType": "image",
                    "fileName": "movie2.0.jpg",
                    "filePath": "images\\movie2.0.jpg",
                    "fileExten": ".jpg"
                }],
                "videos":[{
                        "id": 12,
                        "fileType": "video",
                        "fileName": "movie2.1.mp4",
                        "filePath": "videos\\movie2.1.mp4",
                        "fileExten": ".mp4"
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 16,
                        "fileType": "video",
                        "fileName": "movie2.2.mp4",
                        "filePath": "videos\\movie2.2.mp4",
                        "fileExten": ".mp4"
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 20,
                        "fileType": "video",
                        "fileName": "movie2.3.mp4",
                        "filePath": "videos\\movie2.3.mp4",
                        "fileExten": ".mp4"
                }]

            }]
        },{
            "id": 2,
            "user": "test@test.com",
            "title": "Test Project 2",
            "desc": "project2 123 project2  123 project2  123 project2  123 project2  123 ",
            "status": "Yes",
            "movies":[]
        }
    ]
}
```

The above output is produced by below code.

I need to merge two object which has same Id so that the inner movies arrays also get append / merged. I have tried many ways but i couldn't get the desire output. Please help.

```
let groupList = [];
await Promise.all(
    await getGroups(user).map(async group => {
    group.movies = [await getMovies(group.movieId)];
    groupList.push(group);
    return groupList;
  }));
```

I found the solution by myself

**Solution:**

**-------------**

The below code returns the exact desired output which is expected.

```
await Promise.all(
    await getGroups(user).map(async (item, key) => {
      item.movies = [];
      groupList[key] = item;
      let movies = (item.movies_list) ?  item.movies_list.split(','): []; // it's looks like "1,2" string so converting it to array
      await Promise.all(
        movies.map( async (id, index) => {
            groupList[key].movies.push(await getMovies(id));
          return groupList;
        })
      ) 
    })
  );
console.log(groupList);
```

**Desire output:**

```
{
    "data": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "user": "test@test.com",
            "title": "test Project",
            "desc": "test 123 test 123test 123test 123test 123",
            "status": "Yes",
            "movies":[{
                "id": 1,
                "title": "Movie 1",
                "desc": "Movie 1 Movie 1 Movie 1 Movie 1",
                "status": "Yes",
                "images":[{
                        "id": 1,
                        "fileType": "image",
                        "fileName": "movie1.0.jpg",
                        "filePath": "images\\movie1.0.jpg",
                        "fileExten": ".jpg"
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 2,
                        "fileType": "image",
                        "fileName": "movie1.1.jpg",
                        "filePath": "images\\movie1.1.jpg",
                        "fileExten": ".jpg"
                    }],
                    "videos":[{
                        "id": 4,
                        "fileType": "video",
                        "fileName": "movie1.0.mp4",
                        "filePath": "videos\\movie1.0.mp4",
                        "fileExten": ".mp4"
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 5,
                        "fileType": "video",
                        "fileName": "movie1.1.mp4",
                        "filePath": "videos\\movie1.1.mp4",
                        "fileExten": ".mp4"
                    }]

            },{
                "id": 3,
                "title": "Movie 3",
                "desc": "Movie 3 Movie 3 Movie 3 Movie 3",
                "status": "Yes",
                "images":[{
                    "id": 8,
                    "fileType": "image",
                    "fileName": "movie2.0.jpg",
                    "filePath": "images\\movie2.0.jpg",
                    "fileExten": ".jpg"
                    }],
                "videos":[{
                        "id": 12,
                        "fileType": "video",
                        "fileName": "movie2.1.mp4",
                        "filePath": "videos\\movie2.1.mp4",
                        "fileExten": ".mp4"
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 16,
                        "fileType": "video",
                        "fileName": "movie2.2.mp4",
                        "filePath": "videos\\movie2.2.mp4",
                        "fileExten": ".mp4"
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 20,
                        "fileType": "video",
                        "fileName": "movie2.3.mp4",
                        "filePath": "videos\\movie2.3.mp4",
                        "fileExten": ".mp4"
                }]
            }]
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "user": "test@test.com",
            "title": "Test Project 2",
            "desc": "project2 123 project2  123 project2  123 project2  123 project2  123 ",
            "status": "Yes",
            "movies":[]
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map)

```js
var moviesData = { "data": [ { "id": 1, "movieId": 1, "user": "test@test.com", "title": "test Project", "desc": "test 123 test 123test 123test 123test 123", "status": "Yes", "movies":[{ "id": 1, "title": "Movie 1", "desc": "Movie 1 Movie 1 Movie 1 Movie 1", "status": "Yes", "images":[{ "id": 1, "fileType": "image", "fileName": "movie1.0.jpg", "filePath": "images\\movie1.0.jpg", "fileExten": ".jpg" }, { "id": 2, "fileType": "image", "fileName": "movie1.1.jpg", "filePath": "images\\movie1.1.jpg", "fileExten": ".jpg" }], "videos":[{ "id": 4, "fileType": "video", "fileName": "movie1.0.mp4", "filePath": "videos\\movie1.0.mp4", "fileExten": ".mp4" }, { "id": 5, "fileType": "video", "fileName": "movie1.1.mp4", "filePath": "videos\\movie1.1.mp4", "fileExten": ".mp4" }] }] }, { "id": 1, "movieId": 3, "user": "test@test.com", "title": "test Project", "desc": "test 123 test 123test 123test 123test 123", "status": "Yes", "movies":[{ "id": 3, "title": "Movie 3", "desc": "Movie 3 Movie 3 Movie 3 Movie 3", "status": "Yes", "images":[{ "id": 8, "fileType": "image", "fileName": "movie2.0.jpg", "filePath": "images\\movie2.0.jpg", "fileExten": ".jpg" }], "videos":[{ "id": 12, "fileType": "video", "fileName": "movie2.1.mp4", "filePath": "videos\\movie2.1.mp4", "fileExten": ".mp4" }, { "id": 16, "fileType": "video", "fileName": "movie2.2.mp4", "filePath": "videos\\movie2.2.mp4", "fileExten": ".mp4" }, { "id": 20, "fileType": "video", "fileName": "movie2.3.mp4", "filePath": "videos\\movie2.3.mp4", "fileExten": ".mp4" }] }] },{ "id": 2, "user": "test@test.com", "title": "Test Project 2", "desc": "project2 123 project2  123 project2  123 project2  123 project2  123 ", "status": "Yes", "movies":[] } ] }

let makeMap = new Map();
moviesData.data.forEach((o) => {
  if (makeMap.has(o.id)) {
    let oldmov = makeMap.get(o.id).movies;
    o.movies = [...oldmov, ...o.movies];
    makeMap.set(o.id, o);
  } else makeMap.set(o.id, o);
});

//console.log(makeMap.entries());
console.log([...makeMap]);
```

Comment: Thanks. But I again need to loop through each element of a map to convert this in to Json which is the format can be used from frontend.

Can we do anything with in below code? where i first time assign the movies to a group movies array?

```
let groupList = [];
await Promise.all(
    await getGroups(user).map(async group => {
    group.movies = [await getMovies(group.movieId)];
    groupList.push(group);
    return groupList;
  }));
```

Comment: No you don't have to loop through each element to convert it to Json, I have changed it and used the same data type you received from the api. As of your code I am not sure if it's going to work because i don't know how the data is initially sent by the api

Comment: I have found solution on my own. I wanted to avoid the extra loop on the data which i am retrieving as final. because it affects the performance when we receive huge number of movies in a group. 

So I wanted to do the group by while assigning the movie for the first time itself. Anyway Thanks a lot for your kind help. It gave me an idea and I'll utilize your solution in other problems on need. Again Thanks a lot for providing me this learning.

Comment: You are welcome, I am glad that you have figured out something that works for you. :)